# Weird Trimming Issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, io

I have a weird trimming problem here. I have a txt file of about 500, 000 lines of words. But each line starts with 1), 2), 3)... etc. But the problem here is there isn't just one space inbetween 1) and the word, there are often multiple spaces, and sometimes even a space before the 1), like, right at the start of the line.

I'm not sure how I can just remove all of that stuff that starts before the actual word. But I am 100% sure that there is *always* a space right before the first word.

How can I go about trimming it this way?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

*Example:*

textfile.txt:

```
1) Awesome stuff here 
2) wow 
3) ldfjg ldfk gjldfkg jldfk gjldfkg this line is to be kept too 
4   ) and this too! this is great content 
5 ) gotta love content 
6) content is ok..
   7     ) this is a little odd.
```

Comment: Have you tried sugaring?

Comment: Wth is sugaring? Google tells me its something to do with body hair removal lol

Comment: The lines starts only with these numbers or do you have other numbers like 100) 101) and so on? (You talk of 500.000 lines)

Comment: @Steve - thanks for that - i just modified the code a little to acomodate for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest function is TrimStart :

```
 string cleaned = line.TrimStart(' ',')','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0');
```

it matches all your samples and is easy to adapt.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that. I think that's a sign I should go to sleep now. Thanks for your help!